# AJAX, jQuery, javascript for a chatroom

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I was following a tutorial and I came across the current problem. This is my first time using the ajax method. I copied and saved jQuery version 1.7.2.min.js in a folder. My php code seems to be working fine, the only thing that seems off is the code for the ajax part.

This code is in a folder called "includes"

```
<div id="messages"> 

<!--Javascript-->

<script type= "text/javascript" src= "script/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src= "script/auto_chat.js"></script>
</div><!-- Messages -->
```

This is the javascript in a folder called "script" named auto_chat

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'script/Chat.php' ,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#messages').html(data);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

There is a file called `Chat.php` containing code that links to the database.

When it runs it should show all the messages inside of the database. Instead it gives me blank and not even errors. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my method?

This is the my Chat.php

```
<?php
    require('../includes/database/connect.db.php')

    function get_msg(){
        $query = "SELECT `Sender`,`Message` FROM `chat`.`chat` ORDER BY `Msg_ID` DESC";
        $run = mysql_query($query);
        $messages = array();

        while($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $messages[] = array('sender' => $message['Sender'],
                               'message' => $message['Message']);
        }

        return $messages;
    }

    function send_msg($sender, $message) {
        if(!empty($sender) && !empty($message)) {

            $sender = mysql_real_escape_string($sender);
            $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

            $query = "INSERT INTO `chat` . `chat` VALUES (null,'{$sender}','$message')";
            if ($run = mysql_query($query)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }else {
            return false;
        }

        }


    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        if(send_msg($_POST['sender'],$_POST['message'])){
            echo 'Message Sent';
        }else{
            echo 'Message Failed to sent';
        }
    }   

    $messages = get_msg();
    foreach($messages as $message) {
        echo '<strong>' . $message['sender'] .' Sent</strong><br />';
        echo $message['message']. '<br /><br />';
    }


?>
```

And this is all of my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    require('includes/core.inc.php');


    function get_msg(){
        $query = "SELECT `Sender`,`Message` FROM `chat`.`chat` ORDER BY `Msg_ID` DESC";
        $run = mysql_query($query);
        $messages = array();

        while($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $messages[] = array('sender' => $message['Sender'],
                               'message' => $message['Message']);
        }

        return $messages;
    }

    function send_msg($sender, $message) {
        if(!empty($sender) && !empty($message)) {

            $sender = mysql_real_escape_string($sender);
            $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

            $query = "INSERT INTO `chat` . `chat` VALUES (null,'{$sender}','$message')";
            if ($run = mysql_query($query)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        if(send_msg($_POST['sender'],$_POST['message'])){
            echo 'Message Sent';
        }else{
            echo 'Message Failed to sent';
        }
    }


?>



<html lang = "en">
    <head>

    <!--Page TItle --!>
    <title>Chat Application </title>

    <link type="text/css" rel= "stylesheet" href= "includes/main.css" />

    </head>
    <body>

<div id="input">
<form action = "index.php" method = "post">
    <label>Enter Name:<input type = "text" name = "sender"/></label>
    <label>Enter Message:<input type = "text" name = "message"/></label><br />
    <input type = "submit" name = "send" value = "Send Message"/>


</form>

</div> 


<div id="messages"> 
<?php
    $messages = get_msg();
    foreach($messages as $message) {
        echo '<strong>' . $message['sender'] .' Sent</strong><br />';
        echo $message['message']. '<br /><br />';
    }
?>

<!--Javascript-->

<script type= "text/javascript" src= "script/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src= "script/auto_chat.js"></script>
</div><!-- Messages -->


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check your log file to see if Chat.php is throwing any errors. Or enable php error reporting. `data` is probably blank on return, try adding the fail part to see if it is actually failing and update your question

Comment: Does your `Chat.php` file print out anything (using something like `echo`)? These outputs are the ones which will be sent as the response to the AJAX request.

Comment: Yes my chat file has echo in it. And what do you mean by adding the fail part?

Comment: I am little confused reading your directory structure. Are `auto_chat.js` and `Chat.php` in the same directory? If so, you wouldn't need to call it as `script/Chat.php`, rather just `Chat.php` because the JavaScript code (if included via a script tag) will execute relative to its own file path.

Comment: That maybe an issue as well, but ight now it does not make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, we found out that the problem was a simple missing semicolon on chat.php:

```
require('../includes/database/connect.db.php');
```

:)

Comment: That does not seem to work either. Its weird its not even giving me any errors, if I write nonsense into Chat.php or auto_chat.php. Could that mean that Im not connecting to the source properly?

Comment: I just added my Chat.php and index.php, maybe that will help a bit.

Comment: In that case, make sure that your ajax call is actually hitting the server, you can do that by opening Chrome Developer's Tools (just press F12) and watching the Network tab.

Comment: So Im looking in the code to see if the script actually is shown?

Comment: Now I dont think that my jquery is working right. its in the same file as auto_chat.js, I cannot even get an alert to work.

Comment: Well that might be your problem, make sure that the script is in the page and being executed, after that, you can use the developer's tools  to check if a network request to your chat.php is being made every second. In order to do this, check the Network tab: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fgtIm.png

Comment: ok, so I just did that and it says in the network tab that my jquery file has an error of 404 not found. But thats weird because I have the  src pointing to my jquery file in includes/script

Comment: awesome so I got the jquery to work, and I saw it give an alert message as well. It still however does not run my other code

Comment: Yes so I got the Chat.php to show as well. However now its giving me an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chatroom/includes/script/Chat.php on line 4 "

Comment: This is a PHP error, on line 4 you have your SELECT statement, and I noticed that the previous line doesn't have and ending semicolon: require('../includes/database/connect.db.php');

Comment: Oh thats embarrassing...BUT! Finally works, thank you so much. That Chrome Developer tool is going to help a lot in the future as well!

Comment: Nice, I'm just going to update the answer to leave it properly documented. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, new to this :S Can you also add that I had an issue with directing to jquery properly? :)